# Print om sign with pi

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity, pi

This time I will give you an easy challenge:
Print the [Om](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om) sign with \$\pi\$!(Sorry for many challenges with \$\pi\$)

Here is the om sign drawn using pi numbers:

```
            59  0  64
              230781
3.14159
      26      502884
     535 83279     1971
   89 433              6939
       79    44         937
       323    749     510
    84            58209
626
```

#### Here is the sequence I used to order the numbers of \$\pi\$:

[image: om sign]

## Rules

- There will be no input(except it has to be)
- The program should print the sign to STDOUT
- Its's [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins!
- You must include all the spaces and line breaks in the original text.

Good luck

Comment: Is it kolmolgorov complexity?

Comment: @Third-party'Chef' What is kolmolgorov complexity?

Comment: [kolmogorov-complexity] is a tag for challenges that have no input and a fixed output. The name comes from theoretical computer science.

Comment: @Third-party'Chef' Yes it is. I added the tag.

Comment: Looks pretty boring. Can anyone beat [Bubblegum](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Bubblegum)?

Comment: We need to output that exact text?  This could be a lot clearer in the question

Comment: @user202729 How many bytes is that anyway? By comparison, Charcoal's compression takes 85 bytes.

Comment: @Neil I got 85 bytes in Bubblegum (zopfli) as well.

Comment: @Ad Yes your right

Comment: After this post, someone is downvoting All my posts. Please add a comment why it'a happening so.

Comment: @Tanmay This will never happen. Serial-downvoting will be cancelled automatically by the system.

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 91 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
•Eó£ƵZ₃|ã
xWм7qèý`ÚA¿нÏ9,ÖcPÇŸ›ÎŸt¤,,ûUÅ¨ù—¤ï`ÿ¾ζ@η@••7¼P•в•pÏ{ʒÂfĆ¨¿ZF•15вú•DŠ\•4в£»31DT/:
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AaQAW/9vc2FiaWX//@KAokXDs8KjxrVa4oKDfMOjCnhX0Lw3ccOow71gw5pBwr/QvcOPOSzDlmNQw4fFuOKAusOOxbh0wqQsLMO7VcOFwqjDueKAlMKkw69gw7/Cvs62QM63QOKAouKAojfCvFDigKLQsuKAonDDj3vKksOCZsSGwqjCv1pG4oCiMTXQssO64oCiRMWgXOKAojTQssKjwrszMURULzr//w)

**Explanation:**

```python
•Eó£ƵZ₃|ã
xWм7qèý`ÚA¿нÏ9,ÖcPÇŸ›ÎŸt¤,,ûUÅ¨ù—¤ï`ÿ¾ζ@η@•
                 # Push compressed integer 31746388586852694571167828992290814184914816000404856451284780420784056983357043462437313025051647834765116670748406087616
 •7¼P•           # Push compressed integer 502885
      в          # Convert the larger integer to base-502885 as list:
                 #  [59,0,64,230781,314159,26,502884,535,83279,1971,89,433,6939,79,44,937,323,749,510,84,58209,626]
•pÏ{ʒÂfĆ¨¿ZF•    # Push compressed integer 60230047425392376760356855
             15в # Convert it to base-15 as list:
                 #  [12,1,1,14,0,6,5,5,0,4,3,0,13,7,3,8,7,3,4,4,11,0]
ú                # Pad the integers in the first list with leading spaces,
                 # where the amount of spaces is that of the second list at the same indices:
                 #  ["            59"," 0"," 64","              230781","314159","      26","     502884","     535","83279","    1971","   89","433","             6939","       79","   44","        937","       323","   749","    510","    84","           58209","626"]
•DŠ\•            # Push compressed integer 880633
     4в          # Convert it to base-4 as list: [3,1,1,2,3,3,3,3,2,1]
       £         # Split the list of strings into parts of that size:
                 #  [["            59"," 0"," 64"],["              230781"],["314159"],["      26","     502884"],["     535","83279","    1971"],["   89","433","             6939"],["       79","   44","        937"],["       323","   749","    510"],["    84","           58209"],["626"]]
        »        # Join each inner list by spaces, and then each string by newlines
31               # Push 31
  D              # Duplicate it
   T/            # Divide the copy by 10: 3.1
     :           # Replace the "31" with "3.1" in the string
                 # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Note that all the leading spaces (except for the first integers in the line) are decreased by 1 because the `»` joins by spaces.

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how the compressed parts works.

---

Since I was curious, I also made a program using the actual PI-digits and drawing them in the specified pattern one by one using the Canvas builtin `Λ`. Which surprisingly enough is not that much larger (**97 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)**):

```
2žs•3]]\´ë:O•23в£J•ΘüÁи‘•11в0šúS•2q₄BeçqÌÂ§ßI/ÖÅ?¨L×Σ₃ÛuÌÎvêmtTYx¡n‡¢lΛf4ÙI₁¿çÑv•9в.Λ46Â:„ 4„3..;
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f6Oi@4kcNi4xjY2MObTm82sofyDEyvrDp0GIvIOvcjMN7Djde2PGoYQaQZ2h4YZPB0YWHdwWDFBU@ampxSj28vPBwz@GmQ8sPz/fUPzztcKv9oRU@h6efW/yoqfnw7FKgXF/Z4VW5JSGRFYcW5j1qWHhoUc652Wkmh2d6PmpqPLT/8PLDE8uAxlle2KR3braJ2eEmq0cN8xRMgISxnp71//8A)

**Explanation:**

```python
2            # Push a 2
žs           # Push an infinite list of PI digits: [3,1,4,1,5,...]
  •3]]\´ë:O• # Push compressed integer 243177533433411924
   23в       # Convert it to base-23 as list: [11,2,5,2,3,22,3,3,5,3,2,10,1]
      £      # Split the PI-digits into parts of that size
       J     # Join each inner list of digits together:
             #  [31415926535,89,79323,84,626,4338327950288419716939,937,510,58209,749,44,5923078164,0]
•ΘüÁи‘•      # Push compressed integer 342434478685
 11в         # Convert it to base-11 as list: [1,2,2,2,5,3,3,7,7,1,10,2]
    0š       # Prepend a 0: [0,1,2,2,2,5,3,3,7,7,1,10,2]
      ú      # Pad the strings with that many leading spaces to the integers:
             #  ["31415926535"," 89","  79323","  84","  626","     4338327950288419716939","   937","   510","       58209","       749"," 44","          5923078164","  0"]
       S     # And convert it to a flattened list of characters
•2q₄BeçqÌÂ§ßI/ÖÅ?¨L×Σ₃ÛuÌÎvêmtTYx¡n‡¢lΛf4ÙI₁¿çÑv•
             # Push compressed integer 1107440116348129217561550864085059321059233554362962027078200378907904337318203317830295973758995759889862300097
 9в          # Convert it to base-9 as list:
             #  [2,2,2,2,2,4,2,4,6,6,6,5,2,2,3,2,2,3,6,6,6,6,5,2,5,6,6,6,6,1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,2,2,2,4,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,5,6,6,2,2,2,5,6,6,6,2,2,5,6,6,6,6,6,2,6,2,2,2,2,7,6,6,6,6,6,6,6,2,2,7,6,6,8,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2,1,6,6,6,6]
.Λ           # Use the Canvas builtin with these three lists, where
             # - the 2 is the length of each line
             # - the list ["3","1","4",...," "," ","0"] are the characters to draw
             # - the list [2,2,2,...,6,6,6] are the directions
  46         # Push 46
    Â        # Bifurcate it (short for Duplicate & Reverse copy): 64
     :       # Replace the 46 with 64 in the string
  „ 4„3..;   # Replace the first " 4" with "3."
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?* and *How to compress integer lists?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand how the compressed parts works.

So we use the following options for the Canvas builtin:

- \$a\$ length: `2` (all lines are of size 2; or basically 1 since they're overlapping previous lines)
- \$b\$ the characters we want to display, which are the digits of PI with the spaces we added to travel around
- \$c\$ the directions, where `8` is a reset to the origin where we started, and the other directions are:

```python
7   0   1
  ↖ ↑ ↗
6 ← X → 2
  ↙ ↓ ↘
5   4   3
```

Here some of the first steps:

```python
char: 3; direction: 2→
3

char: 1; direction: 2→
31

char: 4; direction: 2→
314

char: 1; direction: 2→
3141

char: 5; direction: 2→
31415

char: 9; direction: 2→
314159

char: 2; direction: 4↓
314159
     2

char: 6; direction: 2→
314159
     26

char: 5; direction: 4↓
314159
     26
      5

char: 3; direction: 6←
314159
     26
     35

char: 5; direction: 6←
314159
     26
    535

char: space; direction: 6←
314159
     26
    535

char: 8; direction: 5↙
314159
     26
    535
  8

char: 9; direction: 2→
314159
     26
    535
  89

etc.
```

Also note how I take advantage of the palindromized part `535` here so I'm able to draw those digits backwards. With most other digit-substrings I have to first go to the correct position with spaces before drawing the actual digits in direction `2→`.
I use this same palindroized approach also for the digit-substrings `323` and `626`.

The reason the first `3` of the PI-digits is replaced with a `4` is because we use a length of 2 (since lines are overlapping), which causes a minor issue in this case when we reset to the origin location with 'direction' `8`. Since we had to insert the dot anyway this doesn't really matter too much.
The `46` to `64` is because we couldn't move around to the next section with spaces like we did with all the other digits for the final `0`, since it's encapsulated inside other digits and we can't reach it.

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/175520/52210) for an in-depth explanation of how the Canvas builtin works.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES8),  <s>156 152</s>  151 bytes

```javascript
_=>`Qk2 SH
2755Q
1C.4USW
Bq4SGG6
6LxSK4xOC5
13n5Ch2DOE
ZbJoBKP
3Zr990 6AS
11gJYN0
7Q8`.replace(/[0-Z]+\w?/g,s=>''.padEnd((n=parseInt(s,36))%16)+(n>>4))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcjLjoIwFADQ/f0KNxPbKEh5FF2AGRnjiEYljTGiRitU5kFapEb9e/Qszx@/c53Vv9XNkCoXzSVojkF4Sv7tFvsG2/e8BEhkumu2gdHVZZMJBTp/spn7XEYeEEd60Y/9tRxDeo7VaLYCJ60HA6tFPxkQUsTbhQV@0j@ZtahKngnU21lGeujsH8Ne0dVB2G6bFc/HMkdIBhWvtZjKG9Jdh2L8QSjuIBmGLsZNpqRWpTBLVaALescL)

#### How?

A group of \$k\$ spaces followed by a number \$N\$ is encoded as \$16N+k\$ in base 36 and upper case.

*Example:*

```
"            59" -> 16 * 59 + 12 = 956 -> "QK"
```

The following rules apply to separate a string from the next one:

- If it's followed by a line-feed or a period, we leave it as-is.
- If it ends with a letter, we put it in lower case.
- Otherwise, we use one of the spaces that should have been encoded in the next group as a separator.

As a result, all strings can be unambiguously matched with `/[0-Z]+\w?/`.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 111 bytes

```
•DIÿ₅εïΩǝ>Î*.}Öδµ¼ËüúMeĀ¡ζ¿†)в¡Óa×CÁØÒвÕï#â’“¡TÞm×a¿ǝ¬=ß/L@&„@’…ë¼ïæW5éÓ#c∞ðbΣh¬Á‚q”›?иøç,G$X•12B'§Åu„ 
‡31DT/:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AckANv9vc2FiaWX//@KAokRJw7/igoXOtcOvzqnHnT7DjioufcOWzrTCtcK8w4vDvMO6TWXEgMKhzrbCv@KAoCnQssKhw5Nhw5dDw4HDmMOS0LLDlcOvI8Oi4oCZ4oCcwqFUw55tw5dhwr/HncKsPcOfL0xAJuKAnkDigJnigKbDq8K8w6/Dplc1w6nDkyNj4oiew7BizqNowqzDgeKAmnHigJ3igLo/0LjDuMOnLEckWOKAojEyQifCp8OFdeKAniAK4oChMzFEVC86//8)

```
•...•12B'§Åu„ \n‡31DT/:  # trimmed program
                      :  # replace...
                 31      # literal...
                      :  # with...
                 31      # literal...
                   D /   # divided by...
                    T    # 10...
                      :  # in...
                ‡        # replaced each character of...
        '§Å              # "ab"...
           u             # in uppercase...
                ‡        # with corresponding character of...
            „ \n         # literal (\n is newline)...
                ‡        # in...
•...•                    # 12929493392715033775373083693785395621840635578238991913835355382477224495770768407855388223047936086665789536281935915002520324655471900188866985320315060383798192979161318650352714212687144153060399193782953565620356798...
       B                 # converted to base...
     12                  # literal
                         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [///](https://esolangs.org/wiki////), 147 bytes

```
/a/    //b/     5/a   b9  0  64
aaa  230781
3.14159
a  26 b02884
b35 83279a 1971
   89 433aaa  6939
a   79a44aa 937
a   323a749b10
a84a   b8209
626
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY07DoMxCIN3TuETNOHxJ3AcIlXq0C33V0rDYOQPLO9v7s97n9Oyoaa1dTeelqUrgA4Mo8zyon06k77Y@An6k4HVxd1o6QNXmZHgmEyV9oCp3uQIvf@ou1mR0Hm9iua0WNwp3W6nSw8aMs75AQ)

Comment: [141 bytes](https://tio.run/##HU3LDUMxCLtnCiYo4ZMExgnoST30lv2V0vrkn@zz2ef9nHsxsW3EQADEjQG4C8Ojx9QsGix9GTV5kdLw3Dwr72ymGUMGmPDyHeSL0hxU5LcQ06XKUBGoluGySgpLeVr9QT3B9P9m3L1Nnvd@AQ "/// – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl](https://www.perl.org/) + `-p`, 117 bytes

This program contains unprintables so the TIO link is to a Bash program that loads the program from a reversible hex dump.

```pl
}{s//
     u0z
Q0�1
3.HI9
TlV�
o5�U9M�
�e3a
�f	�7
Z3�9m0
�
  tN9
x6/;s/[^\d
.]/15>($x=ord$&)?$"x$x:$x-58/ge
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZJNb9NAEIbP7K94BVELh4zX@@0mhEt7bCVK4cCX5NhrGimNozqhBsRvD7OOEYUDe1jtzM48fuddL8vu9tD3Nab3oNVmu9/RbtVige1qutpM2zvarmfiocK0epxCvjhRMzxDd9s@dMhzj@W3Xeyw2uDNzfnF9bXYxvs1ptu/uubzOU5PZ0JU5Y6Di6tz/lJWx6/ZZr9eH37@6LKM9iTpu6DXknKhifaCbmj9jgS1luhtQZd8JIp8VaZD84S8oPccFnQnU2Z3VYjeZbMu@/D5Yy3oU5bbxfNJ/7K9rycnL15NnvaT/mzST23IvsQDqzjIcZ3B134Jr1UD1cgK3koFLXnzpSwho805DAF4JJaSWHEk5MzQOZdqrSIq7y1kKR2s4c1V1iHEBLKuAXJKA9JxQKJ2ZKjEsDJHqK2FLqSFqUOeQBqF5gtntWYxnhm/TaHRlJGhmeGSDulDAWmcgywKD@2HnE0CpUEwugDK1NwQeToaOTIMM1honQzgJhMiZOUNTOQmWfoA7dgovfQaYPPpaD4N5o8MywzV2CVstBWcYZCKtuacZietjlBBGfiga2B4MPrzYCPDpVkar7idS5VTBXSTToolKJN0lANDMePfRx4ZfvBUc33jPPuH/63hx/gF)

This was [generated using the following program](https://tio.run/##bZDdjtMwEIXv/RSjbkQTljZxEjc2VUGIq72Gu3ZZuY3bRKR2ZHu3XQGvTrDdFFEJK5F/zsx3ZqYXuiPDcAfG6rYHtd@DbQRYzduulQeQ4uR2gUy6kVGaLhG6cwGtAS36ju@EAd51oJ@lcblg@vB0am0TMJ@@fH54gF3DtY/XwghpPdVr8vm4FTrghBbA3S/Fi9BwVO5oGy4Bl1diK4GDLwSO/LsntBYEN69gFdTtfu8IjsytcLy9VkdQnhqcjas9hmSD36a7RsedkAfbxNGbJEkPIvQzthI6uVRlIMbZDFOW/LcXboFQuB@DIWawWo06qRLnh9fZjD5u6p9rPGNuD86E3jvXq@lXP0T3ObSEk@a979H71GKnak89Ne2ugVqJEORkNxwj/Jj9lW/Vi0hQ9LSa/vph0nQ6j57m03Rp0vW3TY3mjykmH@LovFK6drYfo8k5Or@PzjNCXQnTJep1Ky1cxvFuAttXKwxCk@UwwD@LMIAMYFEiuFl5kVUUo2KOS0zYKOaLMSnLKR0zSEGAFnnFwg2zCvt3yqAsilvkghVXEFzCy/KvyIrqqhV5SKzKC5LgLCi0vKmb5hlDi3zxW/W2VdIMs6z/Aw) which uses RLE for spaces and stores runs of digits as bytes where possible.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 122 bytes

```
l59b0b64¶n230781¶3.14159¶f26f502884¶e535a83279e1971¶c89a433n6939¶g79d44i937¶g323d749e510¶d84l58209¶626
{`[a-z]
 $&
T`l`_l
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Dco9DgIhEEDhnlNYGDsNzA/M3MPOGGGFNZuQLYyV3osDcDGke8n73uWz7WkMU1kXu3jqbQe0QVxveHHkWHtbwa9sQWTewshJEIIWp2Gqp2gixN0rTvoKmok2xTAbAXMgLexsb1mosoCdyIM3v3hL5@/dHI4nc401PuoYfw) Uses letters to run-length encode spaces. (The `a`s could be spaces but I couldn't be bothered to special-case them in the [encoder](https://tio.run/##VY6xDsIwDET3fIXHVggUx05iS1T9iW6Amg4MSBVD1YmfD5C2iN5293wnT/f58Rxy7hKkwRymLvVjGlPVnpsr1tVlOL5utek@UZ@KqdpmCXOGP3kFsACBDezkyEZBQydk9LpCF9aSdSJrw5MHIRe1ONSI31wUmGg/GZS2IVjOmX9QKW6MXClGXiY92kKEd3@Ls2qCC28).)

Answer (score 1):

## [Deadfish~](https://github.com/TryItOnline/deadfish-), 842 bytes

```
{i}cc{i}{i}ii{c}cc{i}{i}iciiiic{d}{d}dddddcc{i}iiiiiic{d}ddddddcc{i}{i}iicddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{i}{i}ii{c}cccc{i}{i}ddcicdddc{i}dddcic{d}iiic{{d}iiiiii}ic{{i}dddddd}icdddddciiiciiicdddciiiiciiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{i}{i}iicccccc{i}{i}ddciiiic{d}{d}ddcccccc{i}{i}icdddddciiciiiiiiccddddc{{d}iiiiii}ddc{i}{i}iiccccc{i}{i}icddciic{d}{d}dc{i}{i}iiiicdddddcdciiiiiciic{d}{d}dddddccccc{i}{i}dddc{i}ddcddcddddddc{{d}iiiiii}ic{i}{i}iiccc{i}{i}iiiicic{d}{d}dddddc{i}{i}cdcc{d}{d}i{c}cccc{i}{i}iiciiicddddddciiiiiic{{d}iiiii}iiic{i}{i}iiccccccc{i}{i}iiiciic{d}{d}dddddcccc{i}{i}cc{d}{d}ccccccccc{i}{i}iiiiicddddddciiiic{{d}iiiiii}dddddc{i}{i}iiccccccc{i}{i}dcdcic{d}{d}icccc{i}{i}iiicdddciiiiic{d}{d}dddddccccc{i}{i}icddddcdc{{d}iiiiii}iic{i}{i}iicccc{i}{i}iiiicddddc{d}{d}{c}cc{i}{i}iciiicddddddcddc{i}dc{{d}iiiii}iiic{{i}dddddd}iiiicddddciiiic{{d}iiiiii}ddddc
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVJBDgMhCHxRH9UMbcq5R@PbLSIokN3UmM0ywgyM0utJb/5@HmM07oB8ZDM3nAAsC426bJpLT5gdpgMqDgma4CujzyiyeqLgM1VPSYNVE2tnwCbQNXsmsrYE@/f@vGpxeC/IgnGSeHa4YYMpcDNHKcQh3SnsjEuUUS0MbZkF0F1l0yyBPdOtA8xbUDRbfQxzz/4YdoQu@jYtg4FakpWyhVRd3C6A9kicO9g93xi45JBdyxOVWzGi@si9bbuQ6lB4iZvoakKM8QM)

The longest answer so far, and proud of it.